# Custom Collection View Cell Property Throwing Superclass's Error Upon Setting

Tags: ios, properties, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a single view controller acting as both the `dataSource` and `delegate` for a `UICollectionView`.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PhotoCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PIC_CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageWithData:[[_fetchedImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"picture"]];
    if (photo) {
        cell.photo = photo;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

In the above method I instantiate a custom collection view cell and attempt to set the `photo` property of it.

### PhotoCell.h

```
@interface PhotoCell : UICollectionViewCell {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *photo;

@end
```

### PhotoCell.m

```
@implementation PhotoCell

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        //customization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setPhoto:(UIImage *)photo {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(83.0, 83.0), NO, 0.0);
    [photo drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 83, 83)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    if (_photo != newImage)
        _photo = newImage;

    self.imageView.image = _photo;
}
```

Here, I override the `photo` property's setter, allowing for resizing of the passed photo before setting it as the property.

However, when the code executes and a `PhotoCell` custom cell is instantiated, the following error is thrown when attempting to set the `photo` property in the `-cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method:

```
    -[UICollectionViewCell setPhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155c1270
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell setPhoto:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155c1270'
```

It seems that the system is perceiving the custom cell as an instance of its superclass, `UICollectionViewCell`, rather than the actual class, `PhotoCell`. The same error is thrown when not overriding the setter.

Why is the customized cell being seen as an instance of its superclass, causing the setter to be unrecognizable?

Comment: Where are you registering PIC_CELL?

Comment: Look, I mean how, please show the code. You're registering a NIB? Is the class of the cell set correctly in the XIB?

Comment: Whoops! Silly error. Turns out I had `UICollectionViewCell` set as the registering class. I'm using storyboards. The collection view prototype cell present in the storyboad had the right class associated with it. If you'd like to format your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: The answer's a little short, but done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to how you're registering `PIC_CELL`. Wherever its being done, the wrong class is being specified. This might be in the XIB file or in your code.